Trace condition implies matrix is unitary
Question:
Let $U_a$ ($a=1,2,\cdots,n^2$) be unitary $n \times n$ matrices, and suppose that there exists an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ (EDIT: w.l.o.g. we can restrict $M$ to be diagonal[2]) such that
$$\boxed{ \textrm{tr}(U_a^* M^* M U_b) = n \; \delta_{ab} } \;, \qquad \qquad (\textrm{Eq.} 1)$$
where $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A$.
Can one prove that $M$ is unitary? Equivalently[1], can one prove:
$$\boxed{\textrm{tr}(U_a^* U_b) = n \; \delta_{ab}}\; \qquad \qquad (\textrm{Eq.} 2)$$

Comments:
I was able to prove this in a rather brute-force way for $n=2$. Moreover, I performed some numerical checks for $n=3$ and it seems true.
Let me point out that Eq.1 implies that $\{ M U_a\}_a$ is an orthogonal basis for the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices:
$$\forall A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}: \; A = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{a=1}^{n^2} \textrm{tr}(U_a^* M^* A) M U_a \; .  \qquad \qquad (\textrm{Eq.} 3)$$
In particular, substituting $A = I_n$ shows that $M$ is invertible with $M^{-1} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{a=1}^{n^2} \textrm{tr}(U_a^* M^*)U_a$. This means Eq.3 can be rewritten:
$$\forall A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}: \; A = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{a=1}^{n^2} \textrm{tr}(U_a^* M^* M A) U_a = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{a=1}^{n^2} \textrm{tr}(U_a^*A) M^* M U_a  \; .  \qquad \qquad (\textrm{Eq.} 4)$$
[1] To see that this is equivalent, note that Eq.4 implies that $U_b = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{a=1}^{n^2} \textrm{tr}(U_a^* U_b) M^* M U_a$. Hence, $M^*M = I_n$ is equivalent to $\textrm{tr}(U_a^* U_b) = n \delta_{a,b}$ due to the $U_a$ matrices necessarily being linearly independent (as implied by, e.g., Eq. 1 or Eq. 4). 
[2] Suppose we had proven the theorem for diagonal $M$. For a general $M$, let $M = U S V$ be an SVD decomposition of $M$ (where $S$ is a diagonal matrix and $U,V$ are unitary matrices). Then $M^* M = V^* S^* S V$. By Eq.1 we have $\textrm{tr}(U_a^* V^* S^* S V U_b) = n \; \delta_{ab}$. Applying the theorem for the unitary set $\{ V U_a \}_a$ gives us $n \delta_{ab} = \textrm{tr}(U_a^* V^* V U_b) = \textrm{tr}(U_a^* U_b)$, thereby proving the theorem for general $M$. 

If the set ${U_a}$ is closed under taking adjoints, or if an additional condition is added requiring Eq. 1 with the adjoint on $U_a$ swapped to $U_b$ to also hold, then this is true by uniqueness of trace.

@DavidGao Thanks for the comment. So it would be sufficient to prove e.g. $\textrm{tr}(M^* M U_b U_a^) = \textrm{tr}(M^ M U_a^* U_b) $ (or equivalently, $\textrm{tr}(M^* M U_a U_b^) = \textrm{tr}(M^ M U_a^* U_b) $), since then we can use uniqueness of trace. I don't want to add additional conditions, but perhaps it can be derived from $U_a$ being unitary?

Yeah. I don’t know. I don’t see any way to use the fact that they are unitaries to avoid these kinds of extra conditions. But I’m unable to find any counterexamples at the moment either.

@DavidGao It turns out that the way to use the unitary property is by noting $M_a \equiv M U_a$ defines a trace-orthogonal basis with the property that $M_a M_a^* = M_b M_b^*$. In the answer below, I prove that this is sufficient to derive the conjectured property.

$n=\text{trace}\big( U_1^*M^*M U_1\big)=\text{trace}\big(M^*M \big)\implies \det\big(M^*M\big)\leq 1$
by Hadamard's Determinant Inequality and $\text{GM}\leq \text{AM}$ with equality iff $M^*M$ is diagonal with all diagonal entries constant and $=1$, i.e. iff $M$ is unitary. Now consider two Gram matrices.
First, let $G$ be the $n^2\times n^2$ Gram matrix with
$g_{i,j} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\text{trace}\big(U_i^* U_j \big)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\text{vec}\big(U_i\big)^*\text{vec}\big(U_j\big)$
$\implies G=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\mathbf B^*\mathbf B$.
where $\mathbf {B}  :=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c} \text{vec}\big(U_1\big) & \text{vec}\big(U_2\big) &\cdots & \text{vec}\big(U_{n^2}\big)\end{array}\bigg]$
By direct calculation $g_{i,i}=1\implies\det\big(G\big)\leq 1$ by Hadamard's Determinant Inequality.
Second, let $H$ be the $n^2\times n^2$ Gram matrix with
$\delta_{i,j}=h_{i,j} =\frac{1}{n}\cdot\text{trace}\big( U_i^*M^*M U_j\big)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\text{trace}\big( (MU_i)^* (M U_j)\big)$
$=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\Big(\text{vec}\big(MU_i\big)\Big)^*\Big(\text{vec}\big(M U_j \big)\Big)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\Big((I_n\otimes M)\text{vec}\big(U_i\big)\Big)^*\Big((I_n\otimes M)\text{vec}\big( U_j \big)\Big)$
$\implies I_{n^2} = H = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\Big(\big(I_n\otimes M\big)\mathbf B\Big)^* \Big( \big(I_n\otimes M\big)\mathbf B\Big)=\Big(\frac{1}{n}\cdot\mathbf B^*\big(I_n\otimes M^*M\big)\mathbf B\Big)$
Finally, take determinants
$1= \det\Big(\frac{1}{n}\cdot\mathbf B^*\big(I_n\otimes M^*M\big)\mathbf B\Big)=\det\Big(G\Big)\det\Big(I_n\otimes M^*M\Big)=\det\big(G\big)\det\big(M^*M\big)^n $
i.e. Hadamard's Determinant Inequality is met with equality for both $M^*M$ and $G$
$\implies M$ is unitary and $G=I_{n^2}$.

Hadamard's Inequality is arguably simpler than $\text{GM}\leq \text{AM}$ (and even implies it) but it isn't as well known as it should be. If the reader prefers, consider $m\times m$ hermitian PSD matrix $A$ where $\text{trace}\big(A\big)=m$ then $\det\big(A\big)^\frac{1}{m}=\big(\prod_{k=1}^m \lambda_k\big)^\frac{1}{m}\leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_k}{m}=\frac{\text{trace}(A)}{m}=1$ with equality iff all eigenvalues $=1\implies A=I$. Setting $m:=n$ gives the results for $A:=M^*M$ and $m:=n^2$ gives the result for $A:=G$. So e.g. the above proof shows $\det\big(G\big)=1$ which forces $G=I$.

The claim is correct and can be proven as follows. We first introduce a lemma:

Lemma: Let $\{ M_a \}_{a=1,2,\dots,n^2}$ be a trace-orthogonal basis for $\mathbb C^{n \times n}$ (i.e., $\textrm{tr}(M_a^* M_b) = n \delta_{ab}$). Then:
$$ \boxed{\forall A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}: \quad \sum_{a=1}^{n^2} M_a \; A \; M_a^* =  n \; \textrm{tr}(A) \; I_n}$$


Proof: Define $\mathcal M: (\mathbb C^{n^2},\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle) \to (\mathbb C^{n \times n},\textrm{tr}(\cdot,\cdot)): e_a \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} M_a$. It is convenient to graphically denote this as shown in panel (a) below. Then $\textrm{tr}(M_a^* M_b) = n \delta_{ab}$ implies that $\mathcal M$ is a unitary operator, in particular, $\mathcal M^* \mathcal M = I_{n^2}$, which is graphically shown in panel (b). By uniqueness of inverse, we also have the relationship in panel (c). This directly leads to the claimed property, as derived in panel (d) using the graphic (Penrose/tensor/diagrammatic) notation.


From this lemma, we can prove the following theorem:

Theorem: Let $\{ M_a \}_{a=1,2,\dots,n^2}$ be a trace-orthogonal basis for $\mathbb C^{n \times n}$ (i.e., $\textrm{tr}(M_a^* M_b) = n \delta_{ab}$). Then:
$$ \boxed{ \forall a: \; \; M_a M_a^* = I_n \qquad \textrm{if and only if} \qquad \forall a,b: \; \; M_a M_a^* = M_b M_b^* } $$


Proof: One direction is obvious. For the other, let us presume $\forall a,b: M_a M_a^* = M_b M_b^*$. Then
$$ \forall a \in \{1,2,\cdots,n^2\}: \quad M_a M_a^* = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{b=1}^{n^2} M_b M_b^* = I_n, $$
where in the last equality we used the lemma for the special case $A = I_n$.

The conjecture in the OP directly follows as a corollary of this theorem. Indeed, if we define $M_a = M U_a$ (where $M$ and $U_a$ are defined in the OP), we see that $\textrm{tr}(M_a^* M_b) = n \delta_{ab}$ and $M_a M_a^* = M M^* = M_b M_b^*$, such that the theorem tells us $M M^* = I_n$, i.e., $M$ is unitary.
